# Getting combinations back from memoized subset-sum algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, memoization, subset-sum

I've been working on a basic subset sum problem. Given a sum, let's say 6, and the numbers [1,2,3,4,5,6]), I had to find the total number of combinations that totalled s (for s=6: [1,5], [2,4], [1,2,3]).

I've been able to solve this with brute force haven't been able to find a way to memoize it, so my code is unworkable for sufficiently large values of n.

I found a memoized algorithm [here](http://www.markandclick.com/advance.html#SubsetSum) that works quite well, but it only gives me the number of combinations (so, for s = 6, the number of combinations would be 3) -- not the combinations themselves. Is it possible to both memoize this problem (so that I can run it for very large values of s) **and** be able to output the combinations themselves?

Comment: This recursive algorithm is creating a tree of all possible solutions by starting with the total and substracting values, and only returning `1` (adds up all the branches) if it subtracts exactly into the total (i.e. ends at `0`). For large numbers this might struggle to complete within pythons standard recursion depth.

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify your problem using [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) as:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> s = 6
>>> my_list = range(1, s)
# Value of 'my_list':
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> my_combinations = [combinations(my_list, i) for i in range(2, s)]
# Value of 'my_combinations' (in actual will be containg <combinations> objects):
# [[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)], [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)], [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 5), (1, 2, 4, 5), (1, 3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4, 5)], [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]]

>>> my_required_set = [my_set for my_sublist in my_combinations for my_set in my_sublist if sum(my_set) == s]
>>> my_required_set
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Comment: Do not use the `list()` wrapping inside the `my_combinations` definition; it needlessly realizes all the sets of combinations in memory when you only need to iterate them once, one at a time anyway. For smallish inputs, it's not terrible, but combinations have big-O based on the factorial of the input, and even slightly larger inputs could use up all your RAM. Omitting the `list` means you only need to spend CPU, not memory, for processing the rejected items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't offer memoization -- I just edited my original question to try and make that requirement clearer, as it wasn't obvious initially.